# How do I convert a UserDefault value from AnyObject? to an Int so I can save it

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, anyobject

I'm trying to learn how to work with UserDefaults and can't figure out how to store one of the values I need to store.

I have this enum:

```
enum CalculationFormula: Int {

  case Epley

  case Brzychi

  case Lander

  case Lombardi

  case MayhewEtAl

  case OConnerEtAl
}
```

and this class with a property called 'selectedFormula' that I want to be able to store as a NSUserDefaults value:

```
class CalculatorBrain: NSObject {

  var weightLifted: Double
  var repetitions: Double
  var oneRepMax: Double?
  var selectedFormula = CalculationFormula.Epley

  init(weightLifted: Double, repetitions: Double) {
    self.weightLifted = weightLifted
    self.repetitions = repetitions
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    self.selectedFormula = userDefaults.objectForKey("selectedFormula") <-- error
  }
```

The self.selectedFormula line gives me an error:

```
'Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject?' to type 'CalculationFormula'
```

After much searching on SO and reading the Apple documentation I learned a lot about UserDefaults and AnyObject, but didn't find an answer.

I thought I did when I tried to cast it as an Int:

```
self.selectedFormula = userDefaults.objectForKey("selectedFormula") as! Int

// 'Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'CalculationFormula'
```

and

```
self.selectedFormula = userDefaults.objectForKey("selectedFormula") as Int

// 'Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to type 'Int' in coercion
```

I know the preference values need to be one of these types (NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary) but I'm storing an Int so I should be good there.

I'm just stuck and would really appreciate some help. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your enum

```
enum CalculationFormula: Int {
    case Epley, Brzychi, Lander, Lombardi, MayhewEtAl, OConnerEtAl
}
```

extends `Int` you can use its `rawValue`. So you can read/save an `Int` from/to `NSUserDefaults`.

### This is how you save a formula

```
func saveFormula(formula: CalculationFormula) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(formula.rawValue, forKey: "selectedFormula")
}
```

### And this is how you retrieve it

```
func loadFormula() -> CalculationFormula? {
    guard NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.contains("selectedFormula") else {
        print("No value found")
        return nil
    }
    guard let retrievedFormula = CalculationFormula(rawValue: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("selectedFormula")) else {
        print("Wrong value found")
        return nil
    }
    return retrievedFormula
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the enum using `rawValue`:

```
self.selectedFormula = CalculationFormula(rawValue: userDefaults.objectForKey("selectedFormula") as! Int)
```

Comment: This code will crash as soon as no `Int` value is found for that key. Please note that you are using `objectForKey` which returns `AnyObject?` so it can be `nil` or some kind of object.

Comment: @appzYourLife True, but I was assuming he knows proper error checking.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your value as:

```
userDefaults.setInteger(yourValue, forKey: "yourKey")
```

Load your value as:

```
userDefaults.integerForKey("yourKey") // Returns 0 if the value is nil.
```