# Mapping between array of enums and a dictionary of enums

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Provide a `tableView` that allows the user to select a formula name (an enum) that will be set as their default
2. In this view I'll place a checkmark next to the formula that is the current default
3. Their chosen default formula is what will determine which formula is used to calculate a 1 rep maximum amount (the theoretical amount the user could lift based on actual lifts of lesser weight)
4. After calculating the value, the user will be able to save a record of the lifts they did, **the formula used to calculate the maximum**, and the calculated maximum weight.
5. That record will be saved in Core Data with one of the entities being `Lift` which will simply be the formula name
6. I've created a class that I want to handle the work of providing the current default formula to what ever part of the app needs it as well as set the default when a new one is selected.

Here is my enum of the formula names:

```
 enum CalculationFormula: Int {
      case Epley
      case Brzychi
      case Baechle
      case Lander
      case Lombardi
      case MayhewEtAl
      case OConnerEtAl
    }
```

and with [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368830/how-do-i-convert-a-userdefault-value-from-anyobject-to-an-int-so-i-can-save-it) from the SO community, I created this class to handle the management of `userDefaults`:

```
class UserDefaultsManager: NSUserDefaults {

  let formulas = [CalculationFormula.Baechle, CalculationFormula.Brzychi, CalculationFormula.Epley, CalculationFormula.Lander, CalculationFormula.Lombardi, CalculationFormula.MayhewEtAl, CalculationFormula.OConnerEtAl]

  let formulaNameDictionary: [CalculationFormula : String] =
    [.Epley : "Epley", .Brzychi: "Brzychi", .Baechle: "Baechle", .Lander: "Lander", .Lombardi: "Lombardi", .MayhewEtAl: "Mayhew Et.Al.", .OConnerEtAl: "O'Conner Et.Al"]

  let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  func getPreferredFormula() -> CalculationFormula? {
    guard NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.contains("selectedFormula") else {
      print("No value found")
      return nil
    }
    guard let preferredFormula = CalculationFormula(rawValue: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("selectedFormula")) else {
      print("Wrong value found")
      return nil
    }
    return preferredFormula
  }

  func setPreferredFormula(formula: CalculationFormula) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(formula.rawValue, forKey: "selectedFormula")
  }
```

You can see I have an array of the enums in the order I want them displayed in the `tableView` and a dictionary of the enums so I can get each enum's string representation to display in each cell of the `tableView`. Here's how I populate the cell text label which works:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("formulasCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let currentFormula = formulas[indexPath.row].formulaName
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentFormula
    return cell
  }
```

and here's where I'm setting the checkmark anytime a cell in the `tableView` is selected

```
  func refresh() {
    let preferredFormula = defaults.getPreferredFormula()
    for index in 0 ... formulas.count {
      let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
      if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = preferredFormula == index ? .Checkmark : .None
      }
    }
  }
```

As I mentioned at the beginning, I need to do many different things with this enum but to keep this question focused on one thing, I'll stay with this checkmark example which now **doesn't** work after creating my UserDefaultsManager class

The problem is obvious - preferredFormula is now an enum and I can't compare that to the index value which is an Int - but the solution is not. I could get the raw value of the enum but the `rawValues` aren't guaranteed to be in alignment with the cell `indexPaths`. Some ideas I've had are:

1. I could probably change the order of the enum cases so their raw values match the order I've put them in my formulas array, but that seems silly and unreliable
2. I could use the array index values but that seems equally silly and unreliable
3. If I just use the array, I don't have the string representations of the cases to display in the cells

It seems that using the array and dictionary together is a viable but the best I could come up with is maybe creating another dictionary that maps the enums to Ints but that would have the same issues I just listed.

Any guidance someone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to have the `CalculationFormula` as enum from `Int` values? Can't you use enum from `String` values and map their names in the enum instead of making a separate dictionary? Then you could use the array indexes to track which is the `preferredFormula`.

Comment: I made them `Int` so I could match them to the `indexPath.row` of the tableView cells when setting the checkmark on the default. I was having trouble doing it any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have made things a little more complicated than they need to be.

Firstly, you can use a `String` raw value for your enum and avoid the associated dictionary:

```
enum CalculationFormula: String {
    case Epley = "Epley"
    case Brzychi = "Brzychi"
    case Baechle = "Baechle"
    case Lander  = "Lander"
    case Lombardi = "Lombardi"
    case MayhewEtAl = "Mayhew Et.Al."
    case OConnerEtAl = "O'Conner Et.Al"
}
```

Second, Your `UserDefaultsManager` doesn't need to subclass NSUserDefaults, it is simply some utility functions.  Also, you are doing a lot of checking in `getPreferredFormula` that you don't need to.  I would suggest re-writing that class to use a computed property like so:

```
class UserDefaultsManager {

    static let sharedInstance = UserDefaultsManager()

    private var defaultsFormula: CalculationFormula?

    var preferredFormula: CalculationFormula? {

        get {
            if self.defaultsFormula == nil {
                let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                if let defaultValue = defaults.objectForKey("selectedFormula") as? String {
                    self.defaultsFormula = CalculationFormula(rawValue: defaultValue)
                }
            }
            return self.defaultsFormula
        }

        set {   
            self.defaultsFormula = newValue
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if (self.defaultsFormula == nil) {
                defaults.removeObjectForKey("selectedFormula")
            } else {
                defaults.setObject(self.defaultsFormula!.rawValue, forKey: "selectedFormula")
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I have made the class a singleton; although this may have an impact on testability it simplifies issues that could arise if the default is changed in multiple places.

The appropriate place to set/clear the check mark is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so that cell reuse is handled appropriately.  This code assumes that `formulas` is an array of `CalculationFormula`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("formulasCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let currentFormula = formulas[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentFormula.rawValue

    let preferredFormula = UserDefaultsManager.sharedInstance.preferredFormula
    cell.accessoryType = currentForumula == preferredFormula ? .Checkmark : .None
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Paul. It works now, but I have a couple of questions. 1) Is it necessary to make the class a singleton? I read something that made it sound like when NSUserDefaults is instantiated, Swift is smart enough to not instantiate it again the next time it's called. 2) Why is it necessary to have the set/clear checkmark code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? When I have it there, I have to add tableView.reloadData() to get it to appear and it's not smooth whereas my `refresh()` method, which I adopted from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial, is very smooth and there's no visual flicker.

Comment: You can use the refresh approach as well, but you should always set it in cellForRowAtIndexPath. The class doesn't have to be a singleton but if it isn't you need to be careful if you use the UserDefaultsManager in more than one place as the property may not reflect the changed value. NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults is a singleton but that doesn't mean `defaultsForumula` will be updated in multiple instances of UserDefaultsManager